# Merge arbitrary number of text columns based on null condition of consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
dummy_df = pd.DataFrame([{'Name': 'First', 'Value': 1}, {'Name': 'Start of', 'Value': None}, {'Name': 'cut off', 'Value': None}, {'Name': 'Last', 'Value': 10}, {'Name': 'First of', 'Value': None}, {'Name': 'three lines', 'Value': None}, {'Name': 'cut off', 'Value': None}, {'Name': 'Actually last', 'Value': 100}])

            Name  Value
0          First    1.0
1       Start of    NaN
2        cut off    NaN
3           Last   10.0
4       First of    NaN
5    three lines    NaN
6        cut off    NaN
7  Actually last  100.0
```

I have arbitrary numbers of rows where the `Value` column is `NaN` and I would like to combine consecutive `None` rows such that `Name` is concatenated to produce an end result such as:

```
                           Name  Value
0                         First    1.0
1              Start of cut off    NaN
2                          Last   10.0
3  First of three lines cut off    NaN
4                 Actually last  100.0
```

I've tried using some other answers using `df.shift` and `cumsum` to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `cumsum` on `notna` for the blocks, then groupby:

```
s = dummy_df['Value'].notna()
dummy_df.groupby([s,s.cumsum()], as_index=False, sort=False).agg({
    'Name': ' '.join,
    'Value': 'first'
})
```

Comment: If there was an additional third column `Notes`, how would the `groupby` differ?

Comment: @TomNash what would you want to do with `Notes`? You might want to do the same with either of the two functions `' '.join` and `first`.

Comment: Ah yes, just add `'Notes': 'first'` in `agg`, thank you! I was using wrong dataframe and was giving error, but code was correct.